# Xcode bot error: Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots, xcode7.3

I have a project written in Swift with a main target and two test targets: one for unit testing using [quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) framework and it has 3 [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) tests.
The other target has the XCUITests.

So whenever I run Xcode bot integration with our Xcode CI Server, I get the following error:

```
Bot Issue for Acceptance Bot (error)
Integration #63 of Acceptance Bot
Open in Xcode: xcbot://iosci/botID/1229919cecfcd510f090e37aed014a23/integrationID/16a3709d3ae008a68a65ff2fe9bb5a7b

Assertion: Test target MyUITests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted)
File: (null):(null)

Introduced 2 integrations ago

Full logs for this integration are attached.
```

I get this error when I run it into a simulator integration though it runs fine when I connect the CI server with a physical device and run it.

Note: I'm using Xcode 7.3 with Carthage 0.11.

Comment: The answer I gave on this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834219/test-target-myapptests-encountered-an-error-early-unexpected-exit-operation?noredirect=1#comment67913501_39834219 might helpful to others.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same error (although I was using fastlane to run my UI Tests).

The issue was due to the simulator being stuck on a system alert which the UI Tests did not handle. After that all my tests failed and subsequent runs continued to fail as the simulator was not responding.

I logged into the machine and click OK on the disrupting alert and everything was back to normal.

In my case the alert came up since the application was trying to register of APNS and the

"App Name" would like to enable Notifications alert was displayed. Skipping the APNS registration for UI Tests prevented the issue from popping again.

Comment: The thing is, i cant see any running tests when i integrate using the simulator.
As for the system alerts, UI tests has interruption monitors in which will tap on any pre defined system alerts.

Comment: not sure how the above answer is possible given that the CI machine will not show the running simulator