# IOS bot error: Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping -

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots

I have a question regarding build error that occurs when bots perform UI testing.

When I just run the UI tests, it just works fine. However, whenever I use bots to run the UI tests, there is build error and I keep getting build error saying:

"Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping -"

[XCode bot error: Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312500/xcode-bot-error-early-unexpected-exit-operation-never-finished-bootstrapping)

Some proposed solution says that I have to skip the APNs.. In my case the alert came up since the application was trying to register of APNS and the
"App Name" would like to enable Notifications alert was displayed. Skipping the APNS registration for UI Tests will prevent the issue from popping again.

How can I confirm that the alerts are causing the problem? I was not able to check it since simulator shows nothing on CI machine when the tests are performed by bot. Also, could you please specify what steps should be taken to skip the APNS registration for UI Tests? I am using iphone 6s simulator.

I have been stuck here forever.
I would really appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use iphone 6s simulator (iphone 6s or iphone 6s plus). I was using iphone 6 and it caused me a lot of errors including this one.
 The actual reason was that APNS registration could not be skipped using iphone 6 simulator whereas it could be skipped using iphone 6s simulator for me (App would like to enable push notification..). After that, addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription successfully worked for me!