# Xcode 10 XCTest error: "Underlying error: Test session exited(1) without checking in.)"

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm working on getting an iOS project ready for Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2. So far I can build and use the app. UI Tests also run properly.

However, I'm having trouble running Unit Tests, getting the following error:

> MyApp.app (37040) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Test session exited(1) without checking in.)

I've seen the "Early unexpected exit" error before, specially when working on CI and iOS Simulator fails to launch. But I believe this is the first time I see the "Test session exited(1) without checking in" part.

**I would like to add that we are getting this error only when running tests from the Xcode IDE. All tests pass properly when run from the command line with `xcodebuild`.**

Comment: I personally do not have this problem anymore. I believe it got fixed by creating a new scheme for my unit tests and deleting it. But I'm not sure that is what got the issue fixed. A coworker is having this problem now, we are investigating it.

Comment: just switch to legacy buildsystem

Comment: Same is true for us: Tests fail in the IDE but pass fine on command line.

Comment: Why would the build system affect the *test runner*? Our tests compile without errors.

Comment: Anyone still having this issue? I just found this in Xcode 10, and I hit a wall...

Comment: Thanks!! your question itself fixed my issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting and adding Unit tests target worked for me. Don't forget to check new target in "Target Membership" for tests files.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still experience this issue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40332880/2872205) answer helped me. Set *Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries* to *No* in the projects settings. I did it for the UI test target.